# python / will c local change string.punctuation

Tags: python-2.7, locale

According to the docs, `string.punctuation` contains: `String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale.`

If I print `string.punctuation` I get `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

Can I rely on that this string is always the same because it contains all ASCII punctuation characters or is the locale setting somehow important for this?

(I am using Python 2.7 on Xubuntu 12.04 with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`)

Comment: as the text states: "punctuation characters in the **C locale**"
C-locale is independent on other locales.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - barring (very unlikely) future changes to ASCII or the C locale, that set of characters should remain constant.